# Button inside UITableViewCell - how do i find out what cell it's inside?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a button inside every cell of my UITableView, but when the button is triggered, I want to find out which cell it's inside. I could use a tag, or subclass the button and add a indexPath to it, but then the problem comes when I'm deleting or adding cells and I have to keep up with updating all those buttons. Is there another way people can think of doing this well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell*) button.superview;
NSIndexPath * indexpath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `UITableView`'s `indexPathForCell:` method. It takes a cell, and gives you the index path for the cell.

Answer (score 2):

**try this**

```
- (void) buttonAction:(id)sender{
     UIButton *buttonInCell = (UIButton *)sender;
     NSIndexPath *indexPathOfCell = [self.yourTable indexPathForCell:
                              (UITableViewCell *)[[buttonInCell superview] superview]];
}
```

where the buttonInCell hold the sender Button and indexPathOfCell holds the indexPath value of the Cell that has the Particular Button from which the action has been triggered

the above way may not work with iOS 7

**update**

```
- (void)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    UIButton *buttonInCell = (UIButton *)sender;
    CGPoint center= buttonInCell.center;
    CGPoint rootViewPoint = [buttonInCell.superview convertPoint:center toView:self.yourTableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.yourTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath); 
}
```